# Intent filter not work with host

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

This is not working

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:host="foosubdomain.foodomain.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

It works. But I do not need to get all urls.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

url must opened from mail programms. url has such structure: http://foosubdomain.foodomain.com/#object?id=e1162d22-222b-4522-2210-c222102d6022

Use in Qt/C++ project. Tested with Qt 5.8.0, 5.9.1

p.s. It seems that the problem arises because the mail server inserts information for the redirect. It turns out that I already have another question that does not match the header ... How to filter the URL according to the redirected link?

https://mail.mymailserver.ru/m/redirect?url=http%3A//foosubdomain.foodomain.com/%23object%3Fid%3De1162d22-222b-4522-2210-c222102d6022

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for `IntentFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html), the filtering rules are explained in gory detail. Note this:

> If you specify a scheme but no type, only Intent that does not have a
>   type (such as mailto:) will match; a content: URI will never match
>   because they always have a MIME type that is supplied by their content
>   provider.

It looks like you need to provide a "type" filter.